# BehaviorSubject with class instance

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I understand how to use `BehaviorSubject` when it comes to simple types such as `int string bool` etc. But I have just attempted to implement a `BehaviorSubject` for a class instance, and I am very certain that my approach is wrong...

This is what I currently have (which works by the way):

```
//user.model.ts
export class User {
    public accesstoken: string;
    public details: UserDetails;
    public subscriptions: Channel[];
    private loaded: boolean;
}


//user.service.ts
export class UserService {
    public activeUser: BehaviorSubject<User>;
    ...

    // called when we want to update the users details
    public updateUserDetailsFromServer(){
        ...
        // set the instance to the new data.
        this.activeUser.getValue().details = data.details;
        // now update the BehaviorSubject (this feels so wrong)
        this.activeUser.next(this.activeUser.getValue());
        ...
    }
}
```

I am certain that there is a far cleaner way to implement this.

Comment: Could you please add what you're trying to do? From what I understand, you could just use a plain object instead of a class for `User` and use `scan`.

Comment: @SebastianSebald I am trying to update the `details of type UserDetails` of the `activeUser`. I have an inheritance hierarchy and also a series of functions within these classes which I want to keep including accessors and mutators etc.

Comment: Is there a reason why you user is a `class`? Also could you add where your `Subject` is? It is not included in your snippet.

Comment: @SebastianSebald So i can instantiate it and follow good OOP design methodologies and additionally inherit functionality from other classes. (Note that I didn't include the entire class, Im trying to keep the example simple).

Comment: @SebastianSebald So I just realized that I screwed up my example...... `activeUser` is of type `BehaviourSubject<User>` ....whoops.... sorry.

Comment: Hmmm, why is it a `BehaviorSubject`? You can just create a stream (see below answer) and subscribe to it, to get updates for your active user :)

Comment: @SebastianSebald Honestly, I don't have a particular reason for using a `BehaviourSubject` it's just what I've been using... Trying to implement your answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To simplify matters, I didn't create a `User` class. But it should be easy to replace the object with your implementation.

```js
const { Observable, Subject } = Rx;
const input$ = new Subject();


const user = {
  token: null,
  loaded: false,
  details: {}
};


const user$ = input$
  .startWith(Object.create(user))
  .scan((activeUser, { details }) => { 
    Object.assign(activeUser.details, details);
    return activeUser;
  })
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));


input$.next({ details: { name: 'Bob' } });
input$.next({ details: { role: 'Admin' } });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

*EDIT:* Since using a `class` was part of your question:

```js
const { Observable, Subject } = Rx;
const input$ = new Subject();


class User {
  constructor() {
    this.token = null;
    this.loaded = false;
    this.details = {};
  }
}

const user$ = input$
  .startWith(new User())
  .scan((activeUser, { details }) => { 
    Object.assign(activeUser.details, details);
    return activeUser;
  })
  .subscribe(x => console.log(x));


input$.next({ details: { name: 'Bob' } });
input$.next({ details: { role: 'Admin' } });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

---

I would not advise you to use Observables like that. Especially, using a `BehaviorSubject` and then just pulling data from it with `getValue()`. As shown above, I would suggest using `scan` to hold the current value for the user.

In your case the `input$` can be one or multiple (merged) streams that can update the active user (for example your `http` stream). This way, anything that is interested in updated to the active user, can then just `subscribe` to the `user$`.